# r: How to sample from a population of size 1?

Tags: r, sample

I appreciate that sampling from a list of length 1 has little practical use yet all the same I tried the following:

When I run the r snippet `sample(c(1,2,3),1)` then I obtain a random single value from the list c(1,2,3).

When I run the r snippet `sample(c(3),1)` then I would expect the number 3 to always be output but I don't, I seem to obtain the same behaviour as above.

Why is this? How can I sample from a list of length 1?

I found that `sample(c(3,3),1)` does indeed output the intended, but feels not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation for `sample`:

```
If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had looked at the documentation and it says for x `either a vector of one or more elements from which to choose,`. I didn't get further down! Now I see that what I have is `Note that this convenience feature may lead to undesired behaviour`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample()` from the gdata package. This saves you having to redefine resample in each new script. Just call

```
gdata::resample(c(3), 1)
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/resample